# why wakanda client send only 40 as response

Tags: wakanda

Is their any way of increasing the wakanda client pageSize before performing the query to make itreturn us more than 40 value from the datastore.

I tried some query and getting the response to be 40 everytime not more than that.

The attribute of the returned object has a _count of 38654 value in it but i am getting only 40 of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `pageSize` of the query passing it as an option ([query option definition](https://github.com/Wakanda/wakanda-javascript-client/blob/master/src/presentation/query-option.ts)). This options are equivalent to the old Datastore options ([datastore query options](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Datastore/Datastore-Class/query.301-597677.en.html#/Datastore/Datastore-Class/all.301-596744.en.html)).

Example:

```
ds.Company.query({
  start: 0,
  pageSize: 200
})
```

This will return the first **200** results of the query ([query method definition](https://github.com/Wakanda/wakanda-javascript-client/wiki/Base-Services#queryhttpclient-options-dataclassname)). Please consult the [collection documentation page](https://github.com/Wakanda/wakanda-javascript-client/wiki/Quickstart#collection-helpers) to find further helpers (`nextPage` and `more` for instance) to explore the query results quickly.

Comment: If you can add a link to the `nextPage` method documentation to get next pages of a collection your answer would be complete :)
https://github.com/Wakanda/wakanda-javascript-client/wiki/Quickstart#collection-helpers

Comment: is their any better way than this one since i have some 130000 data to be listed from the database

Comment: you can query all the entities with `pageSize: 99999999` but anyway it would take quite a toll on your server to do it in an high traffic situation.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible through the REST API to change the number of returned entities. You can use `$top` or `$limit` properties.

`GET  /rest/Employee/$entityset/CB1BCC603DB0416D939B4ED379277F02?$skip=20&$top=10`

Source : http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/HTTP-REST/Manipulating-Data/toplimit.303-812598.en.html